# Best solution to run node js AND python 24/7

Tags: python, node.js, server, cloud, hosting

My Problem is, that i have a simple node project that does some calculus. In order for it to work, it beforehand starts a python script that webscrapes the internet for the wanted data.

I now want to run this Node script 24/7, obviously with the python script and chromedriver working.

Is this even possible? And if, how?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your problem running it 24/7 ?

Comment: I simply cannot run my PC 24/7 despite that I have work to do on it and it reduce the performance

Comment: I should have stated that in the question

Comment: So what is the problem? If you can't use local machine for this then use a remote one, i.e. buy a server, likely vps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first try looking into remote hosting (platforms like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), offer a great service at a low monthly subscription fee )

If however you're going for local hosting :

You could easily set it up to work on a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/) for a one time payment ranging from $10 to $35 (depending on your budget & power demands).

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for. Now that you mentioned it, I remembered Firebase has this Service available. Thanks!